# Como utilizar pilhas de Monad?

Tags: programação-funcional, haskell

Estudei o tópico de Monad e decidi fazer um programa para testar meus conhecimentos.

```
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class     (liftIO)
import qualified Control.Monad.State        as ST
import           Control.Monad.Trans.State  (StateT (..), evalStateT, get, put)
import qualified Control.Monad.Trans.Writer as WT
import           Data.List                  (sort)
import           Prelude                    hiding (max)
import           System.Random


randomSt :: (RandomGen g, Random a, Num a) => a -> ST.State g a
randomSt max = ST.state $ randomR (1, max)

lottery :: Integer -> Integer-> StateT [Integer] IO [Integer]
lottery 0 _ = get >>= return
lottery n max = do
  xs <- get
  x <- liftIO $ randomRIO (1, max)
  if x `elem` xs
     then lottery n max
     else do put (x:xs)
             lottery (n - 1) max

lotteryWt :: Integer -> Integer -> WT.WriterT [String] (StateT [Integer] (ST.State StdGen)) [Integer]
lotteryWt 0 _ = ST.lift get >>= return
lotteryWt n max = do
  xs <- ST.lift get
  x <- ST.lift . ST.lift $ randomSt max
  g <- ST.lift . ST.lift $ get
  WT.tell [show x ++ " " ++ show n ++ ", state from StateT " ++ show xs  ++ ", state from State " ++ show g]
  if x `elem` xs
     then lotteryWt n max
     else do ST.lift $ put (x:xs)
             lotteryWt (n - 1) max

main :: IO ()
main = do x <- evalStateT (lottery 6 60) []
          g <- newStdGen
          let y = ST.evalState (evalStateT (WT.runWriterT (lotteryWt 6 60)) []) g
          putStrLn $ show $ sort x
          putStrLn $ show $ sort (fst y)
          mapM_ putStrLn (snd y)
```

Eu tenho duas pilhas de Monad's uma `StateT [Integer] IO [Integer]` e a outra `WriterT ...`. Para cada função lottery, eu extraio os valores de cada Monad.

Eu queria entender se esse é o caminho certo para utilizarmos várias Monad. É uma boa prática esse tipo de utilização?

Comment: Fiz algumas pesquisas sobre o assunto [haskell - Avoiding lift with Monad Transformers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054731/avoiding-lift-with-monad-transformers) e [If you're using lift, you're doing it wrongly (probably)](http://blog.ezyang.com/2013/09/if-youre-using-lift-youre-doing-it-wrong-probably/). Mas não achei uma resposta, assim que achar algo, postarei.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, mas note que existem duas variantes de Monad Transformers. A primeira é essa que você está usando, do pacote [`transformers`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers), onde se ganha em conseguir usar muitos monads, mas tem o problema do tipo depender da pilha (e da ordem da pilha).

O outro jeito é usando o estilo [`mtl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl). É parecido com o que está fazendo, mas os transformadores são classes, ao invés de serem wrappers concretos.

(Ao invés de `WriterT w m r` você tem `class Monad m => MonadWriter w m`, que compõe melhor).

Eu me extendi um pouco mais do que gostaria em um exemplo:

Tem uma leitura excelente sobre exatamente esse assunto aqui: https://making.pusher.com/3-approaches-to-monadic-api-design-in-haskell/

Caminha justamente sobre os Monads concretos (que você está usando), os abstratos usando classes e aí uma outra abordagem - apesar de terem outras.

```haskell
-- stack runghc --package mtl --package transformers
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
module Main where

import Control.Monad.Identity
import System.Random

-- transformers
import Control.Monad.Trans.State (StateT, evalStateT)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Writer (WriterT, runWriterT)

-- mtl
import Control.Monad.Writer.Class
import Control.Monad.State.Class

-- transformers ==============================================================

-- No seu programa a pilha é composta por
type AppInteiros m = StateT [Integer] m
type AppLogger m = WriterT [String] m
type AppRandom = StateT StdGen Identity

-- Usando MTL, tem classes de tipo para elas:
-- class Monad m => MonadState s m | m -> s
-- class (Monoid w, Monad m) => MonadWriter w m | m -> w

-- Se o tipo do seu programa agora é:
type AppTransformers r = WriterT [String] (
                        StateT [Integer] (
                            StateT StdGen Identity
                        )
                        ) r

-- mtl =======================================================================

-- Agora ele poderia ser uma classe (!) :)
type MonadAbstratoApp m = ( MonadState ([Integer], StdGen) m
                        , MonadWriter [String] m
                        )

type AppMtl m r = WriterT [String] (StateT ([Integer], StdGen) m) r

main = do
    g <- newStdGen

    (result, logs) <- (evalStateT (runWriterT (run 6 60)) ([], g))
    print result -- x
    print logs   -- [ "Generating random number...", ... ]
where
    -- Isso aqui é hiper genérico e desacoplado. Você poderia ter funções que
    -- explicitam de que tipo de efeitos dependem e as usar sem mais boilerplate
    lotteryWt :: MonadAbstratoApp m => Integer -> Integer -> m [Integer]
    lotteryWt 0 _ = fst <$> get
    lotteryWt n max = do
        xs <- fst <$> get
        x <- randomSt max
        logRandom x
        lottery 10 100
        if x `elem` xs
            then run n max
            else do
                modify (\(_, g) -> (x:xs, g))
                run (n - 1) max

    -- Por examplo:
    randomSt :: MonadState ([Integer], StdGen) m => Integer -> m Integer
    randomSt max = do
        (ts, g) <- get
        let (x, g') = randomR (1, max) g
        put (ts, g')
        return x

    logRandom :: MonadWriter [String] m => Integer -> m ()
    logRandom x = tell [ "Generating random number...", show x ]

    lottery :: MonadState ([Integer], StdGen) m => Integer -> Integer -> m [Integer]
    lottery 0 _ = fst <$> get
    lottery n max = do
        (xs, _) <- get
        x <- randomSt max
        if x `elem` xs
            then lottery n max
            else do
                modify (\(_, g) -> (x:xs, g))
                lottery (n - 1) max
```

Comment: Valeu pela resposta. Eu vou dar uma lida. Eu até cheguei a ler o código fonte do [monad-logger](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-logger-0.3.22/docs/src/Control-Monad-Logger.html) para entender o polimorfismo entre as Monads.

Comment: Parece um bom código pra ler. Talvez escrever uma aplicação usando ajude.